# Qual a diferença entre print e echo no PHP?

Tags: php, console

Já que ambos imprimem um texto na tela, qual seria a diferença entre se usar `print` ou `echo` no PHP?

Quando é mais aconselhável usar qual?

```
echo "echo";
print "print";
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

São bem parecidos. Algumas diferenças:

## [`print`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php)

- Retorna 1 como resultado e pode ser usada em expressões

## [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

- Retorna um tipo `void`, portanto não pode ser usada em expressões
- É possível passar vários argumentos que devem ser impressos separados por vírgula
- É ligeiramente mais rápido

Eu faço de conta que `print` não existe. Nunca precisei usar como expressão que seria o único motivo para usá-lo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu faço de conta que print não existe. A frase mais inteligente que li hoje.

Comment: E ainda foi a primeira que leu :D