# Qual diferença entre echo, print, var_export no PHP?

Tags: php

A [*diferença entre var_dump e print_r*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172775/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-var-dump-e-print-r) já tem [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172779/35406). Porém não dá nenhum detalhe em relação ao o `echo`, `print` e `var_export`.

Qual diferença entre `echo`, `print`, `var_export` no PHP?

Comment: [Relacionada no SOen de `echo` vs `print`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094118/reference-comparing-phps-print-and-echo), em que o `print` literalmente usa o `echo` no seu código interno.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quanto a comparação entre `echo` e `print`:

- Ambos são construtores de linguagem e não função;
- `print` recebe apenas um valor, enquanto `echo` recebe quantos forem necessários;
- `print` retorna sempre um *int* 1, enquanto `echo` não possui retorno;
- `print` pode ser utilizado em expressões, `echo` não (única diferença real entre eles);
- Usar ambos como *statatement* produz um resultado equivalente, com mesmos efeitos laterais, sendo `echo` ligeiramente mais rápido, visto que `print` utiliza `echo` internamente;

Tal diferença já foi discutida aqui:

[Qual a diferença entre print e echo no PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45412/5878)

[echo ou print, qual realmente é a melhor opção?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4943/5878)

## `var_export`

Já o [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.var-export.php) se encaixa mais na mesma categoria de `var_dump` e `print_r`, geralmente utilizados para *debug*. Sua utilização se assemelha bastante ao `var_dump`, porém, ao invés de exibir informações detalhadas sobre a expressão, como tipos, tamanhos, etc, o `var_export` exibe uma representação válida da expressão. Entende-se por representação válida um texto que possui uma sintaxe permitida pelo PHP. Ela é especialmente útil quando você precisa armazenar o valor de uma expressão, em um *log*, por exemplo, que seja possível você copiar/colar para um editor e efetuar operações de testes sobre este.

Compare as saídas de `var_dump` com `var_export`:

```
// var_dump([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
array(5) {
  [0]=> int(1)
  [1]=> int(2)
  [2]=> int(3)
  [3]=> int(4)
  [4]=> int(5)
}

// var_export([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 3,
  3 => 4,
  4 => 5,
)
```

Se o segundo parâmetro de `var_export` for avaliado como verdadeiro, a representação da expressão, ao invés de ser enviada ao *buffer* de saída, é retornada, podendo ser utilizada pelo código, tal como em:

```
file_put_contents("log.txt", var_export($expression, true));
```

O `var_export` é especialmente útil para as perguntas aqui no Stack Overflow, quando o usuário quer mostrar como é a representação de uma expressão que possa ser utilizada pelos outros usuários ao elaborarem a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

De fato quase todas as opções de impressão foram dissecadas em [Diferença entre var_dump e print_r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172775/101) e [echo ou print, qual realmente é a melhor opção?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4943/101).

Então o [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) faz o mesmo que o `print_r()` em um formato um pouco diferente. O resultado é um código válido PHP e pode até mesmo ser usado para avaliar como código e criar alguma execução (não faça isto em tempo de execução, no máximo para um *script* de [*scaffolding*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119731/101) ou algo parecido).

Uma diferença importante é que ele terá problema se um elemento referenciar outro elemento (ou o mesmo) dentro deste *array*. Ele entrará em *loop*.

É possível jogar um resultado em uma variável em vez de imprimir o resultado como no `print_r()`, mas não no `var_dump()`.

Ao contrário do `var_dump()` só interessa os dados e não detalhes do *array*.

Exemplo de saída dele:

```
array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 
    array (
        0 => 'a',
        1 => 'b',
        2 => 'c',
    ),
)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).